# CHtml::link() with inner content

Tags: php, hyperlink, yii

Is there any way to produce this HTML output with help of Yii's CHTML::link() method?

```
<a href="localhost/somecontroller/someaction" class="foo"><i class="bar"></i>My awesome link</a>
```

I require some nested tag in the anchor tag and can't figure out, how do I put  into . CHTML:link() isn't preferred over other methods. If you know, how to implement that by means of CMenu, it'll be also gorgeous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found only one solution. It is escaping the «'» character in the first parameter of *link* method. I know, it is so ugly, but I can deal with it.

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('<i class=\'icon s\'></i>Foo',array('/site/index'), array('class'=>'hover')); ?>
```

Comment: I think it should work to use double quotes instead of escaped single quotes, no? '<i class="icon s"></i>Foo'

Comment: I agree with thaddeusmt, you can use double quotes

Comment: The "clean way" would  be to use CHtml::tag('i', array('class'=>'icon s')) . 'Foo' for the links content.

Answer (score 5):

May be you can try this one.

`<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::tag('i', array('class'=>'bar'), 'My awesome link'), array('somecontroller/someaction'), array('class'=>'foo')); ?>`